# Mathematical Proof of Decay in Tunneling with tunnel lenght L

Tags: quantum-tunneling

Let us suppose we have a particle with energy $E$ and $E<U$ and the potential defined as

$U(x)=0$ for $x<0$ (I)

$U(x)=U_0$ for $x>L$ (III) and

$U(x)=U$ for $0<x<L$ (II)

I find the wavefunction for

region (II)

$$\psi(x)=Ae^{\beta x}+Be^{-\beta x}$$ for $\beta=\frac {\sqrt{2m(U-E)}}{\hbar}$

Is this true ? Because in the site of the hyperphysics it says it should be,

$$\psi(x)=Be^{-\beta x}$$ for $\beta=\frac {\sqrt{2m(U-E)}}{\hbar}$

I am not sure how we can derive this mathematically ? Why the

$Ae^{\beta x}$ term vanishes ?

Comment: In each region you have different coefficients $A$ and $B$. In addition, the wave function should not grow to infinity; thus some growing exponents must have zero-coefficients. Finally, the wave function and its first derivatives at any point must be continuous. These conditions at $x=0$ and $x=L$ give you a unique wave function (up to a common coefficient).

Comment: I can share the solutions for the other regions ? I dont need to find the coefficients but just write the general form of the equation. So you are saying its due to the conditions ?

Comment: In each region you have particular values of $A$, $B$, and $\beta$: $A_{I,II,III}$, $B_{I,II,III}$, and $\beta_{I,II,III}$ due to different values of $U(x)$.

Comment: Yes I know that.

Comment: If $E$ is smaller than any particular value of $U$, then the difference $U-E$ is positive under the square root, so the exponential must decay at $x>0$ rather than grow. Thus $A=0$ to get rid of the growing exponential in the solution.

Comment: Should I define (U-U_0)=V and do all the calculations by that or do I have to do something else ? Since in this sense its confusing

Comment: I do not know, read carefully the problem setup. But you never encounter the expression $U-U_0$, only $U(x)-E$.